# jQuery.get from Spring RestController

Tags: javascript, java, spring, web, spring-restcontroller

How can should I send the data from Spring controller to the client? Do I need to wrap it as Json or is there an easier way?

(noob in web. So, please bear with me)

```
@RequestMapping("/abc")
@RestController
public class ListController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/d", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public StringOrJson? getData() {
    return "myData";
}
```

On the client:

```
function checkBoxToggled(){
    $(document).get('abc/d', function( data ) {
      alert('Data Loaded2:' + data );
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be great if you declare the @RequestMapping as follows:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/d", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
```

You can return simple String response.

Or you can always reutrn JSONObject as follows:

```
return new JSONObject("{'data':'myData'}");
```

In that case the return value in the method signature should be replaced to **JSONObject**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, still not getting it.
WIth "produces='application/json", I get it on localhost/abc/d, however not with jQuery.get.  I get nothing in consoles either..
JSONObject doesn't work both on url and jquery..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify your Controller to:

```
@RequestMapping("/abc")
@Controller
public class ListController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/d", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getData() {
        return "myData";
    }
}
```

And the client should be:

```
jQuery.get("abc/d", function (data) {
    alert('Data Loaded2:' + data );
});
```